# Call REST GET request inside Rules Action

Tags: rules, 8

I created a custom Rules Action that calls a REST API.
I can be able to display `$entityId = $entity->id();` but when I try to use it concatenated in my `$uri` I am getting no result in `$data`.

`$uri = 'http://localhost:8080/api/' . $entityId;`

`\Drupal::logger('test')->notice('Path: ' . $uri); // Displays correct path`

```
try {
  $response = $client->get($uri, array('headers' => array('Accept' => 'application/json')));
  $data = (string) $response->getBody();
  if (empty($data)) {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
catch (RequestException $e) {
  return FALSE;
}
\Drupal::logger('test')->notice('Data: ' . $data); // Displays "Data: []"
```

Its so strange that when I assign hardcoded value for `$entityId = 123;` it does work. I can get the whole api content for specific node in the log.